# How do I see the older versions of my code in Eclipse Git

Tags: eclipse, git

I have a java project in eclipse which is placed under Git for source control. I need to see the old code using the GUI git tool of eclipse in an **easy** way. How do I do this ? I found command line answers for this, but nothing for Eclipse Git GUI. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the User Guide sections on comparing content and using the History view: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Comparing_Content and https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#History_View .

Comment: Thanks ! How did you find those links ? This is what worked for me - right click any java file/resource > team > show in history > double click any revision in the history window that opens up.

Comment: Btw, I can open individual files and see their older versions using the steps I gave above. But, when I select the whole project and do the same thing, it does not work. Please tell me how I can do it for the whole project.